# Everyone loves Fibonacci

Tags: c#, beginner, fibonacci-sequence

I was bored and burnt out on more serious projects.... until I saw [this Computerphile video on YouTube](http://youtu.be/7t_pTlH9HwA). Now I'm inspired again. Now I feel like spending some time implementing that recursive algorithm in a little console program. Fortunately, recursion is unbearably slow in this case. So, I ended up writing a small class that implements a loop algorithm to find any \$F_n\$.

I'm just learning C#, so I'm most concerned with best practices and style. I want to get a good foundation though, so all feedback is welcome.

**Particular Concerns**

- Is my indentation correct?
- Have I named my variables horribly? (I think they smell a bit.)
- Which implementation is better? I'm feeling like it's six of one or a half doz. of the other.
- Should I be concerned about hitting the upper boundary of the `ulong` type? Fibonacci numbers grow very quickly. Is there a better representation of very large numbers?

**Fibonacci**

```
class Fibonacci
{
    private int _n;
    private ulong _value;
    private ulong _FnMinus1;
    private ulong _FnMinus2;

    public int n 
    {
        get { return _n; }
        set { _n = value; } 
    }

    public ulong Value 
    { 
        get {return _value;}
        //set { _value = value; }
    }

    public void Calculate() 
    { 
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n","Can't calculate Fn when n is less than or equal to zero.");
        }
        else if (n == 1 || n == 2)
        {
            _value = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //initialize previous results
            _FnMinus1 = 1;
            _FnMinus2 = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= (n - 2) ; i++)
            {
                _value = _FnMinus1 + _FnMinus2;
                _FnMinus2 = _FnMinus1;
                _FnMinus1 = _value;
            }
        }
    }

    //constructors
    public Fibonacci(int n)
    {
        _n = n;
        Calculate();
    }

    public Fibonacci() { }

}
```

**Implementation1**

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            fib.n = i;
            fib.Calculate();
            Console.WriteLine(fib.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Implementation2**

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci(i);
            Console.WriteLine(fib.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Update:** [Follow up question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54894/does-everyone-still-love-fibonacci).

Comment: Check out this [Fibonacci](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx) implementation while you are at it :)

Comment: For big integers indeed us `BigInteger` class.

Comment: Interesting @AlexiLevenkov. I wonder how well it performs.

Comment: It bears mentioning that it's not the *recursion* that's slow—it's the *naive* recursion that's slow. Implement it with DP and Fib(n) will be O(n).

Comment: @WChargin DP??? The algorithm I tried was Fn = Fn-1 + Fn - 2.

Comment: By your definition you get a overflow by F(94).

Comment: This one **has to be** be nominated in the *Best Question Title* category!

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca what kind of overflow? Integer or Stack? (guessing integer, but better be sure)

Comment: @Vogel612 Of course integer (`ulong` that is) overflow: `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.` Just change the limit in the for loop in the implementation 1 and you will get an exception; unless it's run in an unchecked environment, in which case it overruns happily and silently and just gives out a wrong answer.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca. I noticed late last night (after I posted this) that indeed, console starts silently giving wrong answers around `n = 90` or so.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Indentation and formatting are fine, as is the algorithm itself.

Your naming is inconsistent, compare `n` and `Value`; `_value` and `_FnMinus1`.  There are a variety of conventions to follow, but consistency is the most important thing.

`_FnMinus1` and `_FnMinus2` are only used in one method, so they can be made local to that method.

The API is a little odd:

```
fib.n = i;
fib.Calculate();
int result = fib.Value;
```

It would be more convenient if I could do this with one line, like `int result = fib.Calculate(i)`, which would return the value.  Then it seems that `n` and `Value` are unnecessary.

Furthermore, right now there is nothing that keeps `n` and `Value` synchronized.  The class should maintain the invariant that `Value` is always the `n`th Fibanacci number.  You could do the work in the `n` assignment or mark `Value` as dirty when `n` changes.  Either way you essentially get rid of `Calculate`, so that's another approach.  I prefer getting rid of `n` and `Value`, I just mention this in case you think it makes sense to keep them.

Between Implementation 1 and Implementation 2, it's pretty much a wash.  1 has the benefit of only making one allocation.  Since the class is (going to be) stateless, it's perfectly reusable.  On the other hand 2 declares `fib` inside the loop, which minimizes its scope (which is good).

Comment: Yeah. I broke a golden rule. I implemented features before they were actually needed. Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to have a stateless class, you might as well make it `static`.

Comment: @svick I agree in this specific case.  In general making classes/functions static can prevent DI or other types of polymorphism, so I don't think it's a rule that should be stressed to novices.

Answer (score 14):

Microsoft's .NET style guide [recommends *against* the use of underscores or any Hungarian notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in identifiers.

You're right that overflow will occur for large enough values of `n`.  It is possible to avoid overflow by using [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).  However, that adds a lot of clutter to your program, and is more tedious than you would probably like for a simple educational project.

I think you've missed an important point about object-oriented programming, which is that objects should keep themselves in a self-consistent state.  You've exposed `Calculate()` as a public method, and you expect callers to call `Calculate()` before fetching `.Value`.  That's an unfair burden on callers, and they may neglect to do so.  Rather, a better design would have the `.Value` getter automatically recalculate if necessary.  (The `Calculate()` method should be private.)  An even smarter design would continue where the previous calculation left off (rather than starting from scratch) if `n` has not decreased since the previous call to `.Value`.

Comment: The underscores I get, but I haven't used any Hungarian notation. Fn is mathematical notation. I still don't like those names though. I do need something better.

Comment: Your question didn't contain Hungarian notation. I mentioned Hungarian notation pre-emptively, in case you had the idea of using prefixes, as in `mValue` instead of `_value`.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok. Thank you. I was obviously confused.

Comment: Careful with recommending against Hungarian. The practice being frowned upon is embedding type name in variable name, and the original Hungarian (the actually useful one) was about embedding logical meaning in the name. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: @Kos according to that link, Hungarian notation was originally conceived as a solution for type less languages. In fact, the only time I recommend it myself is for VBScript. Hungarian notation should be burnt with fire.

Comment: @Kos I recently read [what Joel Spolsky had to say about Hungarian Notation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) and I have to say that it changed my mind. A little bit.

Answer (score 12):

**Class Design**

Some of class design is a matter of doing what will cause the least surprise to others.  There is nothing functionally wrong with passing the value into the constructor and reading the answer from a value, or in explicitly setting the count, can calculating; they both work; but a more expected shape would be along the lines of

```
public class Maths {
    public long CalculateFibbonacci(int count){
      // return the calculated value
    }
}
```

which would make the usage

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var fib = new Fibbonacci();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
           Console.WriteLine(fib.Calculate(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Or one could make it a static function in a static class (though, I tend to avoid these as they hinder unit testing). The class as designed (adding extra steps to use class members - n, value) smacks of *It's an OO language so one should use a class.*

**NOTE:**

Although there is nothing functionality wrong with either, *if used properly*, the

```
fib.n = i;
fib.Calculate();
Console.WriteLine(fib.Value);
```

usage has so many dependent steps that it is very error prone in usage and I would *really* push for not using it.

**Coding Style**

Indentation, spacing, bracket position et al. can be considered religious issues that cause endless bickering.  There is a value to having a single style across a codebase because it makes things simpler for reading/reviewing. It is also tedious when two team members have different styles set in their editors and keep changing spacing, bracket position for the whole file every time they make any change, but **THERE IS NO ONE TRUE STYLE** many different styles have developed and the most popular mainstream ones all have their pluses and minuses.

So, if one is working with other people and the majority/consensus style is not totally ludicrous, one should suck it up and use the common style.

That all said, the current code style looks good. It is clear and readable.

Public members of a class should be [Pascal Cased](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and descriptive.  `n` is a bad name for a public member. It tells the user nothing about its meaning or usage.

**Hitting Limits**

For what do you want to use this code?

If it is a programming exercise to check coding styles and designs then unless *'dealing with large numbers'* is one of the design aspects that you wish to address, I wouldn't worry about the result getting too large.

If it has some real world usage then check this usage, to see if it is likely to overflow and if it is, then worry about it.  Worrying about it unless there is a solid need can be considered a form of [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: I'll be using this in some puzzles later, so large numbers are a concern. I agree that `n` is a bad name, but it's not Hungarian notation. It's mathematical notation. F sub n. I'm open to suggestions for a better one.

Comment: I was actually thinking of the _FnMinus1, _FnMinus2 for the Hungarian, but it looks like I was off - they are just abbreviations. My Bad. I'll update the answer. As for n: that there is no better name for it does give a hint that it is not a great fit for a member.  If we take it out and use the function version of calculate `long Calculate(int n)`, then n as a the name of a parameter to the function comes under 'the sort of thing people expect'

Comment: I think I've got a good one. [Ordinal Position](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/14992), but I need to think about how I want the API to work. I'm wondering if there's ever a need to expose N to anything outside of Fibonnacci.

Comment: As I said, splitting the API into too many steps is dubious and there is no need for it here.  Instead of { Create, Set OrdinalPostion, Invoke Calculate, Read Result},  we can  {Create, Invoke Calculate Passing in Ordinal Position and Reading result }  This way, there is no need to store / expose either Ordinal Position or Value(Result) in the class

Comment: I took care of the issue where the class expects its client to keep it in sync. I'm thinking now of whether or not to keep OrdinalPosition and Value hidden away or to implement just a `public Calculate()` function. Thank you for your input. I'll probably post a follow up once I've figured out how I want to handle it.

Answer (score 5):

The answers to most of your questions have been given and aside from consistency in naming and using BigInteger there's not much more to say to the questions however A more general comment would be that Fibonacci sequences makes for an odd class. It's a function more than a class and what you've implemented is basically a way to curry the argument to the function and that leeds to a somewhat odd class design. Not because your design is odd but because the tool is not the best one for the task. If you are modelling a function as a class where does the result then go? as a calculated property or the return value of the single method?

So instead of modelling a function that returns the n-th number you could create a class that represents a fibonacci sequence

```
class FibonacciSequence : IEnumerable<BigInteger>
{

    IEnumerator<BigInteger> IEnumerable<BigInteger>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        BigInteger prev1 = 1;
        BigInteger prev2 = 1;
        yield return 1;
        yield return 1;
        while (true)
        {
            var next = prev1 + prev2;
            yield return next;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = next;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<BigInteger>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

you could then use it like this

```
new FibonacciSequence().Take(2).Last();
```

to get the second number in the sequence. Of course you could use memoization and an indexer to speed up consequetive calls. The below does that (not thread safe)

```
class FibonacciSequence : IEnumerable<BigInteger>
{
    List<BigInteger> list = new List<BigInteger> { 1, 1 };

    IEnumerator<BigInteger> IEnumerable<BigInteger>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.Concat(iterate()).GetEnumerator();   
    }

    IEnumerable<BigInteger> iterate()
    {
        BigInteger prev1;
        BigInteger prev2;
        prev1 = list[list.Count - 2];
        prev2 = list[list.Count - 1];
        while (true)
        {
            var next = prev1 + prev2;
            list.Add(next);             
            yield return next;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = next;

        }
    }

    public BigInteger this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= list.Count)
            {
                list.AddRange(iterate().Take(index - list.Count + 1));
            }
            return list[index];
        }

    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<BigInteger>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic advice. Thanks.